# How to serialize three models with many to many relationships in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, orm

I have three base models:

```
class User(models.Model):
    displayName= models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Cell(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class List(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

And three many-to-many relationships between them:

```
class UserCell(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    cell = models.ForeignKey(
        Cell,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    value = models.SmallIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=['user', 'cell'],
                name='unique_UserCell'
            )
        ]

class UserList(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    target_list = models.ForeignKey(
        List,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=['user', 'target_list'],
                name='unique_UserList'
            )
        ]

class CellAssignment(models.Model):
    target_list = models.ForeignKey(
        List,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    cell = models.ForeignKey(
        Cell,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    idx = models.SmallIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['idx']
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=['target_list', 'idx'],
                name='unique_cellAssignment'
            )
        ]
```

My view is given a List.id and a User.id and I want to return data in the following format, or something similar:

```
{"List.id": 2, "List.title": "The Big List of Cells", "List.created_date": "2020-10-02T18:14:02Z",  "cells": [{"target_list.id": 2, "Cell.id": 6, "CellAssignment.idx": 0, "Cell.title": "The first cell", "UserCell.value": 4}, {"target_list.id": 2, "Cell.id": 12, "CellAssignment.idx": 1, "Cell.title": "This is the second cell and so on", "UserCell.value": 9}, ...]}
```

Is it possible to do this by nesting serializers, or should I query the relationships separately and join the data in the view? Any info on the difference in performance between the two approaches would be additionally appreciated.

Edit (12/24). Current Serializers:

```
class UserCellSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserCell
        fields = '__all__'

class CellSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Cell
        fields = ['id', 'title']

class CellAssignmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    cell_title = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='cell.title')
    cell_value = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='cell.user_cell.value')

    class Meta:
        model = CellAssignment
        #target_list and cell are not strictly needed below, as of now. good for debug tho.
        fields = ['target_list', 'idx', 'alt_title', 'cell_title', 'cell_value']

class ListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    cell_details = CellAssignmentSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = List
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'created_date', 'cell_details']
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships

You can make nested serializer.

1. Make each serializer for model.
2. Make all serializers nested.

First, Just make each serializer and then merge all of them for nested.
It should be working.

Updated,

```
cell = models.ForeignKey(
        Cell,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="user_cells"
    )
```

Then, you can access user_cell from cell like

```
  cell_instance.user_cells.all()
```

or whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks for your response Sam. I do know that I _can_ make nested serializers. I have gotten the list fields serialized along with a list of cell objects. I am stuck on getting a UserCell.value coordinated with each of the cells.
I'm also wondering if going through the convoluted model/serializer process is worth the effort when it seems much easier to manually join the tables by id (like would normally done with relational SQL).

Comment: You can get data with reversed foreign_key. Use [related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)
It makes you get UserCell data.

Comment: Yes, I think that related_name will be the key. I have added it to UserCell on the cell ForeignKey: `related_name='user_cell'`. For the following serializer, cell_title is showing up but cell_value is not:
`class CellAssignmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    cell_title = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='cell.title')
    cell_value = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='cell.user_cell.value')` It seems that I cannot drill into the adjacent relationship?

Comment: Can you add view code before calling CellAssignmentSerializer?

Comment: The view is not doing any work right now, and cell assignments are actually nested into the ListSerializer with `many=True`. So I'm just getting my requested list by id with `targetList = List.objects.get(pk=pk)`, then handing it over to the ListSerializer: `list_serializer = ListSerializer(targetList)`

Comment: Edited my question to include my current serializers. I'm curious if having the field `UserCell.value` is a problem, in that 'value' is a commonly reserved word for objects...